# Mysql update BUT keep the old data?

Tags: php, mysql

In a customer CMS the customer can update their personal information, like change their address and first/last name. I use a mysql `UPDATE` query for that.

Problem with working like this is, is that people can change their information. E.g. change their name from `john doe` to `asdfdas`. I would like to SAVE their old information.

What are my options? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You'd either have to keep multiple records in the same table, with some way of telling what the current 'active' record is, or an archival table you can copy the old data to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new columns for the data being updated `column` would be `prior_to_update_column`

On update, move the old info into `prior_to_update_column`

If the user updates again, append to the `prior_to_update_column` seperated by `,` (to look like an array).

This should keep all the previous info the user updates

Comment: I like this one, because I don't have to create new tables. How would I go about moving the old data to a new column though? I'm using a `foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){` loop and I don't think I can access the old information if a `$_POST` is already set.

Comment: save the $variable = $_POST['form_value']; --> then right before you update with the new data, update the prior_to_update_column with the current information (append a comma to the end (like array) ) -> then update with the info from form. This can be done in a stored procedure to save mysql trips (for efficency). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user has a unique ID you could have an `old_user_information` table and when you do an update also do a new entry into that table. The table would have an autogenerated ID as well as the unique user ID and the rest of that users past information.

A user could have multiple rows in this table but only one row in the real `Users` table.

Edit: If I were you I would write a stored procedure that does both of these things so that it is easier to manage if things change.

Answer (score 1):

You can make table that contains something like this

```
`yourTableID, field, value, date`
```

and update this with a trigger. You write an `update` trigger that adds the old value if it is changed. Look [at the manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to find out more about triggers.

If you don't want to use triggers you could obviously do the same in your logic: just update the history table with the old value. But this needs some trickery to find out *if* you need to update it, but nothing to complicated.

For easy retrieval what happened you might want to add something like "oldvalue" AND "newvalue", but the latter isn't really needed, as it is either in the next update as 'old' value, or it is the current value.

Answer (score 0):

add an additional field name version 
and use Insert instead of update

Answer (score -2):

あの答えのとうりに、やってない。
UPDATE `table name` SET `column`=`column`+'new value' WHERE `condition`